# sas proc means. Fill in gaps

Tags: sas

[image]

was wondering if anyone knows how to fill in the missing boxes with the categories. Also is it possible to format proc mean generated values like mean and median? Was trying to add a dollar $ sign to it using the dollar infomat.

```
title1   height= 0.25in  'Total Medical Expenditures by Sex, Age and Smoking Status';
title2   height= 0.15in  'U.S Adults, Medical Expenditure Panel Survey 2018';
proc means data=mepsUse n mean median std maxdec=0 ;
 var   totexp18;
 class sex ageGrp currSmoke;
 format sex MaleFemale. ageGrp AgeCategory. currSmoke Smoker.;
run;
```

Comment: The format statement works with PROC MEANS.  An informat would have no effect because the values are already numbers and are not being created by converting text.  So there would be no place that the informat would ever be used.

Comment: The displayed output does not have the blanks filled in. If you create an output data set it will have the values filled in and then use PROC REPORT to have more control over the displayed values. Or PROC TABULATE also allows you more formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create a data set.  For example.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class stackods completetypes;
   ods output summary=classsummary;
   class sex age;
   var height weight;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]